# Java: Select JTable row, retrieve value, click button that uses value

Tags: java, button, jtable

I have this JTable which shows "Jobs" and a button "Apply" that would be clicked after single clicking this row of Job in this JTable. I need this button to retrieve this row value and then bring users to another panel which will use this value. I have an error in my Apply button "jobid cannot be resolved", how do I retrieve the jobid that was selected from the JTable and be used on the button?

My JTable code:

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(184, 198, 628, 338);
    add(scrollPane);
    setLayer(scrollPane, 3);
    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(table);
    setTableModelFromDB();
    setLayer(table, 3);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(table.getTableHeader());
```

JTable's MouseAdapter:

```
            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ex) {
            if (ex.getClickCount() == 2) {
             int rowSelected = table.getSelectedRow();
             if(rowSelected >= 0){
              int jobid = (Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(rowSelected, 0);
              Job j1 = Job.retrieveJobById(jobid);
              JLayeredPane contentPane = new JobPanel(mf, j1);
              mf.setContentPane(contentPane);
              mf.setVisible(true);

            }
           }
            else if (ex.getClickCount() == 1) {
                 int rowSelected = table.getSelectedRow();
                 if(rowSelected >= 0){
                     int jobid = (Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(rowSelected, 0);
                    }
            }
          }

         });
```

Apply Button:

```
        JButton ApplyJob = new JButton("Apply");
    ApplyJob.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // check for selected row first
            if (table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
                // remove selected row from the model
                JLayeredPane contentPane = new ApplyJobPanel(mf, jobid);
                mf.setContentPane(contentPane);
                mf.setVisible(true);     
               }
        }
    });
    ApplyJob.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    ApplyJob.setBounds(233, 559, 137, 50);
    setLayer(ApplyJob, 3);
    add(ApplyJob);
```

Comment: You are declaring `jobid` in an `if` statement, so the scope of that variable is limited to that block. You need to move your declaration out of the `if` statement. You can still set the value there, but the variable needs to be declared outside of that block.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `jobid` does not exist in the ActionListener you created for the `ApplyJob` button. You have to remember that things like `ActionListener`s, `MouseAdapter`s, etc. are actually *inner classes*, which is to say they have their own scoping and their own private member variables.

As it stands, the `jobid` variable you create in the `MouseAdapter` goes out of scope the moment the `mouseClicked()` method exits, hence why your `ActionListener` can't see it.

A much better and more idiomatic approach would be for the `ActionListener` on the `ApplyJob` button to talk to the table's data model and get the values needed for the `ApplyJobPanel` constructor by querying the data model with the currently selected row from the table.